# How can I break up an ASP.NET project into smaller sub-projects?

Tags: asp.net

I can't rewrite in MVC (at this time), but leaving it as one giant project is causing too many problems. I would like to make each of my 10 top-level folders into a separate ASP.NET project.

The code is currently written in ASP.NET 1.1 style (i.e. no master pages) but I can upgrade to any version of .NET.

Comment: Just create 10 web application projects in your solution, and setup IIS virtual directories for each 10 folders to point to a different website.

Comment: Will they share session state?

Comment: Yep - as long as you use SQL as your session provider (not ASP.NET State Service). See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402785/sharing-session-state-between-2-asp-net-applications-using-sql-server

Comment: Do you have use different dll for your running code ? or you have all your code on app_code directory ?