# ASP.Net MVC 4 Shared Session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

We have been attempting to share session between multiple MVC sites.  We need to do this so that we can integrate our session with a couple of legacy webform sites.

We have implemented the CSASPNETShareSessionBetweenSubDomains class from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETShareSessionBetween-021daa39 and made changes to the stored procedure per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2007/01/25/sharing-asp-net-session-state-across-applications.aspx.

We have also added the httpCookies handler into the web.config per [Sharing session state between 2 ASP.NET applications using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402785/sharing-session-state-between-2-asp-net-applications-using-sql-server)

When we test between two subdomains, they appear to have the same session id, however, when we select from ASPStateTempSessions, we see the sessionId that is stored contains the sessionId that is appended with some other value:

SessionId from cookie: srvgqxts1yzuqnswr5pv0eoo

Values from table:

- srvgqxts1yzuqnswr5pv0eoo0e8cc1f9
- srvgqxts1yzuqnswr5pv0eoo15890198

I appears that this value being appended is causing the session to be unique between the two subdomains.  I'm hoping that someone has experience sharing session between MVC applications and even better on how to share that same session with legacy webform sites.

Thanks in advance