# Share same session between web applications across different domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I tried sharing same session between two asp.net applications across subdomains from the [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527105). Its working fine. Is there any way to share same session between two different domains / different server.
 I need to share same session between two web applications so that the session time out in one application should expire the second application.
 Any suggestions.

Comment: Use the database. Sessions won't work across different domains.

Comment: are you talking about different domains on the web (i.e www.abc.com and www.xyz.com), or different domains in active directory?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service

Comment: @daryal  the one you linked to is talking about sharing session state between different web applications on the same server, this one is sharing across domains on different servers

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402785/sharing-session-state-between-2-asp-net-applications-using-sql-server

Comment: @David yes. two different websites hosted in different servers.

Comment: @MattWhetton hi. in that link, they shared session data using cookies in the same domain only.